# Select rows from DB SQL Server 2017 with dates condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

```
Select *
from [User]
where  [Date1] - [Date2] < 7
```

SQL Server 2017.

I want to select rows where *[Date1] - [Date2] less than 7 days*.

Dates are in format YYYY-MM-DD (object).

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time difference calculation in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555152/time-difference-calculation-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Datediff` function

```
Select * from [User] 
where datediff(dd, date2, date1) < 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
select u.*
from user u
where date1 >= date2 and
      date1 < date2 + interval '7 day';
```

Note that date arithmetic is often specific to databases.  This is ANSI-standard syntax, but other databases have similar functionality.